# Ros2 Foxy Python custom SRV type error

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's the traceback from the error,

```
[Intersection(i_d=0, ins=[1011, 1804], out=[1000], clear=True), Intersection(i_d=1, ins=[1103, 1001], out=[1002], clear=True), Intersection(i_d=2, ins=[1002, 1008], out=[1004, 1010], clear=True)]
[INFO] [1627053698.780029518] [intersection_action_server]: Checking intersection
[INFO] [1627053698.780460999] [intersection_action_server]: Incoming request
Type: Incoming RFID: 1002
[INFO] [1627053698.780763667] [intersection_action_server]: Sending back: Clear
[INFO] [1627053053.366115161] [intersection_action_server]: Checking intersection
[INFO] [1627053053.366806566] [intersection_action_server]: Incoming request
Type: Incoming RFID: 1002
[INFO] [1627053053.367215310] [intersection_action_server]: Sending back: Clear
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mrumel/fisher_agc/AGCROS/install/server/lib/server/intersection_manager", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('server==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'intersection_manager')()
File "/home/mrumel/fisher_agc/AGCROS/install/server/lib/python3.8/site-packages/server/intersection_manager.py", line 70, in main
rclpy.spin(intersection_manager)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/__init__.py", line 191, in spin
executor.spin_once()
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 711, in spin_once
raise handler.exception()
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/task.py", line 239, in __call__
self._handler.send(None)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 426, in handler
await call_coroutine(entity, arg)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/executors.py", line 381, in _execute_service
srv.send_response(response, header)
File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/service.py", line 72, in send_response
raise TypeError()
TypeError
```

Here's my .SRV file first, it's filename is IntersectionManager.srv

```
string ask
---
string is_clear
```

My Service node

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from agc_interfaces.srv import IntersectionManager
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional, List
import json
import ast

@dataclass
class Intersection:
    i_d: int
    ins: List[int]
    out: List[int]
    clear: bool

intersectionList: List[Intersection] = []

class IntersectionActionServer(Node):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('intersection_action_server')
        self.srv = self.create_service(IntersectionManager,'intersection_manage',self.execute_callback)
        global intersectionList
        with open('/home/maxunm/fisher_agc/AGCROS/scs_rfids.json') as f: 
            data = json.load(f)
        dicts = data['rfids'] #Extract all the RFIDs from data
        i = 0
        for rfid in dicts:
            for s in rfid['args']:
                if "intr" in s:
                    split_s = s.split(';',-1)
                    ins = ast.literal_eval(split_s[1])
                    out = ast.literal_eval(split_s[2])
                    intersectionList.append(Intersection(i,ins,out,True))
                    i = i+1
        print(intersectionList)
                    

    def execute_callback(self, request, responce): 
        self.get_logger().info('Checking intersection')
        ask_list = request.ask.split(",")
        which = ask_list[0]
        rfid_num  = int(ask_list[1])
        self.get_logger().info('Incoming request\nType: %s RFID: %d' % (which, rfid_num))
        for intersect in intersectionList:
            if which == "Incoming": #AGV coming into an intersection
                if rfid_num in intersect.ins: #Which intersection the rfid it's at is in
                    """Check for if that intersection is locked or not"""
                    if intersect.clear:
                        responce.is_clear = str('Clear')
                        intersect.clear = False
                    else:
                        responce.is_clear = str('Blocked')
            else: #AGV leaving intersection
                if rfid_num in intersect.out:
                    if intersect.clear:
                        responce.is_clear = str('ERROR')
                        intersect.clear = True
                    else:
                        responce.is_clear = str('OK')
                        intersect.clear = True
        self.get_logger().info('Sending back: %s'%(responce.is_clear))
        return


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    intersection_manager = IntersectionActionServer()
    rclpy.spin(intersection_manager)
    rclpy.shutdown()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And then finally the tester node:

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from agc_interfaces.srv import IntersectionManager
import time


class IntersectionTester(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('intersection_tester')
        self.cli = self.create_client(IntersectionManager, 'intersection_manage')
        while not self.cli.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=1.0):
            self.get_logger().info('Intersection Manager not available, waiting again...')
        self.req = IntersectionManager.Request()
    
    def send_request(self):
        self.req.ask = input("Enter the test string: ")
        self.future = self.cli.call_async(self.req)







def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    intersection_tester = IntersectionTester()
    intersection_tester.send_request()
    while True:
        while rclpy.ok():
            rclpy.spin_once(intersection_tester)
            if intersection_tester.future.done():
                try:
                    responce = intersection_tester.future.result()
                except Exception as e:
                    intersection_tester.get_logger().info(
                        'Service call failed %r'%(e,)
                    )
                else:
                    intersection_tester.get_logger().info(
                        'Responce received: {}'.format(responce)
                    )
                break
        time.sleep(2)
    rclpy.shutdown()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

On the input I am entering: `Incoming,1002` and it crashes with the traceback after trying to return as far as I can tell.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383069/ros2-foxy-python-custom-srv-type-error/) by [maxunm](https://answers.ros.org/users/70708/maxunm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2021-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/service.py", line 72, in send_response -  raise TypeError()  - TypeError

The issue is with your service code in the execute_callback() function. The return is there but you have not defined the variable. In other words, it is returning nothing but in your service file, you have stated that it is returning a string.

```
return <your return string>
```

Just make that change in your service code > execute_callback() function.

Hope it helps you. feel free to drop a comment if it is not working.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [maxunm](https://answers.ros.org/users/70708/maxunm/) on 2021-07-23**:
Oh my gosh, I cant believe I forgot to return the response. Thank you for your help